# Find specific file and delete it if exists

Tags: powershell

I am using a couple of variables but normally I use the object returned from the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to find files and use an if statement that is altered.

But how can I find a specific file in directories and if it finds it then delete it? This was the code I made:

```
$VM_NAME="Test"
$search=Get-ChildItem -Path B:\Virtualservers\Disks\Users\* -include $VM_NAME.vhdx -filter *.vhdx -Recurse 

if ($search.Name -contains "$VM_NAME.vhdx") {remove-item ??? }
else {write-host "Continue.."}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just *pipe* your `Get-ChildItem` result to the `Remove-Item` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path B:\Virtualservers\Disks\Users\* -include $VM_NAME.vhdx -filter *.vhdx -Recurse | 
    Remove-Item -Force
```

In case there is no file found, this will also work.

Answer (score 2):

remove-item have this options, just do it

```
$VM_NAME="Test"
remove-item B:\Virtualservers\Disks\Users\* -Recurse -include "$VM_NAME.vhdx"
```

Answer (score 1):

So rather than using an If statement you want to use a `Where-Object` the lower part of your code would be something like

```
$search.Name | Where-Object {$_ -like "*$VM_NAME.vhdx*"} | Remove-Item
```

You can use -eq and drop the "*" rather than -like if $VM_NAME.vhdx will match your file names exactly.

Comment: Isn't that Where-Object obsolete because he is using the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet with `-filter`  and `-include` parameter?